# Long regex replace requires multiple passes to finish - why?

Tags: python, regex, data-analysis

I've checked the site for an answer to this question and exhausted Google and my own patience trying to answer it myself, so here it is. Happy to be pointed to the answer if this is a dupe.

So I have a long regex--nothing complicated, just a bunch of simple conditions piped together. I'm using it to remove the piped words from the beginnings and ends of named entities I've extracted from news article data. The use case is, many of the names have these short words within them (think Centers for Disease Control and Prevention) but I want to remove the words when they appear at the beginning or end of the name. E.g., I don't want "Centers for Disease Control" counted differently from "**the** Centers for Disease Control" for obvious reasons.

I used this regex string on a large (>1M) list of named entities in Python 3.7.2 using the following code ([file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yru45yqrww028b4/pnames.csv?dl=0)):

```
with open('pnames.csv','r') as f:
    named_entities = f.read().splitlines()

print(len([i for i in named_entities if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 146

short_words = "^and\s|\sand$|^at\s|\sat$|^by\s|\sby$|^for\s|\sfor$|^in\s|\sin$|^of\s|\sof$|^on\s|\son$|^the\s|\sthe$|^to\s|\sto$"

cleaned_entities = [re.sub(short_words,"",i) 
for i 
in named_entities]

print(len([i for i in cleaned_entities 
if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 80 (huh, should be 0. Let me try again...)

cleaned_entities2 = [re.sub(short_words,"",i) 
for i 
in cleaned_entities]

print(len([i for i in cleaned_entities2 
if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 1 (better, but still unexpected. One more time...)

cleaned_entities3 = [re.sub(short_words,"",i) 
for i 
in cleaned_entities2]

print(len([i for i in cleaned_entities3 
if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 0 (this is what I expected on the first run!)
```

My question is, why doesn't the regex remove all the matching substrings in one pass? i.e., why is `len([i for i in cleaned_entities if i == 'the wall street journal'])` not equal to 0? Why does it take multiple runs to finish the job?

Things I've tried:

- Restarting Spyder
- Running the same code in Python 3.7.2, Python 3.6.2, and equivalent code in R 3.4.2 (the Pythons gave the exact same results, and R gave different numbers but I still had to run it several times to get to zero)
- Running the code only on the substrings that match the regex (same result)
- Running the code only on the strings that equal "the wall street journal" (works in one pass)
- Substituting the regex `"^the "` in the above code (fixes all matches in one pass)

So yeah, any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Not sure what your input is, but it really sounds as if only the first and the last words were removed by each `re.sub` run. You could use quantified groupings, like `^(?:(?:a(?:nd|t)|by|for|in|o[nf]|t(?:he|o))\s+)+|(?:\s+(?:a(?:nd|t)|by|for|in|o[nf]|t(?:he|o)))+$`, to match consecutive whitespace-separated words you want to remove. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D1XUUW/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression will only ever remove one layer of unwanted words per pass. So if you had a
sentence as:

```
and and at by in of the the wall street journal at the by on the
```

it would have needed many passes to completely remove everything.

The expression can be rearranged to make use of `+` to indicate one or more occurances of as follows:

```
import re

with open('pnames2.csv','r') as f:
    named_entities = f.read().splitlines()

print(len([i for i in named_entities if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 146

short_words = "^((and|at|by|for|in|of|on|the|to)\s)+|(\s(and|at|by|for|in|of|on|the|to))+$"
re_sw = re.compile(short_words)

cleaned_entities = [re_sw.sub("", i) for i in named_entities]

print(len([i for i in cleaned_entities if i == 'the wall street journal']))
# 0
```

The process can be sped up slightly by pre-compiling the regular expression. It would be even faster if you applied it to 
the whole file rather than applying it on a line by line basis.